# Derivation of curl of magnetic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, classical-electrodynamics, differentiation

I am having trouble in one part of derivation of curl of magnetic field, from Biot-Savart law. The attached picture is from Griffiths - Introduction to Electrodynamics.

I got all the parts, but only consfused with the term that I have put in the red rectangular. How those this product on left side, become those two on the right side; by which product rule or by what logic?

[image]

Comment: The product rule is probably on the inside of one if the covers it defined somewhere else in the book (possibly chapter 1).

Comment: Did you look at product rule 5 that they mentioned? It is just the vector dot product equivalent of the product rule you know with some rearrangement. These are located near the front or the back of the book but can be derived by hand too.

Comment: I honestly can't understand why you would ask in "by which product rule or by what logic?" when the text right below your box is "(using product rule 5)".  Please answer the question Triatticus asks above.  Are you asking for an explanation of Griffiths' product rule 5?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Physics SE! Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri it is not product rule specified number 5. Product rule number is for equation down. But as Avantgards answer it is just the partial integration and I did not see it coming

Comment: solidbastard, I have the 4th edition in front of me open to page 233 and the fact is this:  you're not telling the truth when you write "Product rule number is for equation down".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll consider a simplified, one dimensional version where $J$ and $F$ are just two functions depending on $x$. And $\partial \equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$. Then they are basically saying:

$$J \partial F = \partial(FJ) - F \partial J,$$

which is the product rule. You can generalize this to vector calculus with multiple dimensions.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is just the partial integration, got it! :)